# Is there a way to set when variables are used in a decision tree?

Tags: r, decision-tree, rpart

I've been using rpart to build decision trees. There is a certain key variable that I want to be the first node of the tree. Is there anyway to set when a variable is used in the decision process? Or to inflate the importance of a variable so that it used earlier?

I've tried running the model with different combinations of variables, sometimes getting the one I want to show up as the first node. But I would like a way to put it there every time.

Comment: Hello Paul: First: Provide a reproducible example so a relevant answer can be delivered.

Comment: With respect of your question: i Think you can fake the tree this way: First, fit a tree with only one variable (your key variable)  as data, and the response (a [stump](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_stump)). You control this with control(maxdepth=1). Then, fit two separate models for each branch.

Comment: A different way that produces a single tree. Use the `cost` parameter to `rpart`.  You can adjust the cost of using the key variable to be very low and guarantee that it will be used first.   However, don't set it too low or it will be used repeatedly.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.